# Jquery image loading canceled

Tags: javascript, jquery, shadowbox

I am using shadowbox to open up pop up. After the work has been done on the pop up, I am appending a row on the parent page and then I close the shadowbox as done in the code.

```
var row$ = $("<tr id='"+data.entityContactId+"'>");
row$.append("<td align='left' valign='top'>"+data.entityContactId+"</td>");
row$.append("<td align='left' valign='top'>"+data.fName+"</td>");
row$.append("<td align='left' valign='top'>"+data.mName+"</td>");
row$.append("<td align='left' valign='top'>"+data.lName+"</td>");
row$.append("<td align='left' valign='top'>"+data.functionalRole+"</td>");
row$.append("<td align='left' valign='top'>"+data.designation+"</td>");
row$.append("<td align='left' valign='top'>"+data.status+"</td>");
row$.append("<td align='left' valign='top'><a rel='shadowbox[]; width=1000; height=565;' 
        href='../contactDetails/contactDetails.html?entityContactId="+entityContactId+"&companyId="+entityId+"&companyCode="+entityCode+'>
        <img src='http://26fc614be383109f4ed8-83b958a355d4ec1f6468075626f4c2ef.r23.cf1.rackcdn.com/edit.png' title='View Contact'/></a></td>");
                         ...... more code for appending 2 more images...
window.parent.$("#"+rowID+"").replaceWith(row$);
window.parent.Shadowbox.setup();
window.parent.Shadowbox.close();
```

Functionality wise everything completes well, a row is appended in the table at the parent page. But the images are not appended on the page. I dig into it more and found that the request is being canceled by jquery or something as shown in the file below.!
[image]

Sorry not able to post image due to reputation.

But I can post the network tab of chrome which comes after pressing f12.

Path   -->          Method  -->  status  -->  Type -->    initiator

/edit.png-->      Get  -->    (canceled) pending --> jquery-1.10.js6569

Is there anything I can do to resolve this issue??

Comment: Have you tried stepping into the debugger to figure out where it is going wrong?

Comment: I have updated the image in the question, the error that I got while appending is done.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in the opening and closing of quote and double-quotes (' and ") when you're appending the row containing the image.

I'm gonna try to write it again:

```
row$.append("<td align='left' valign='top'><a rel='shadowbox[]; width=1000; height=565;' 
    href='"../contactDetails/contactDetails.html?entityContactId="+entityContactId+"&companyId="+entityId+"&companyCode="+entityCode'>
    <img src='http://26fc614be383109f4ed8-83b958a355d4ec1f6468075626f4c2ef.r23.cf1.rackcdn.com/edit.png' title='View Contact'/></a></td>");
```

If there are other rows like it, you're gonna need to modify them too.

What I did is: I added a double-quote (") just before the "../contactDetails/cont...", and I removed a + after "entityCode".

**EDIT**

This is something similar to your example. I tried this and it worked well.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Show Image Dimensions Locally</title>
<style type='text/css'>
    body {
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        console.log("document is ready");
        var $row = $("<tr id='newrow'>");
        $row.append("<td align='left' valign='top'><img src='http://eofdreams.com/data_images/dreams/image/image-03.jpg' title='Image' style='max-width: 400px; max-height:200px' /></td>");
        $row.append("<td>New Text 1</td>");
        $row.append("<td>New Text 2</td>");
        $row.append("<td>New Text 3</td>");
        $row.append('</tr>');
        window.parent.$("#row").replaceWith($row);
    });

</script>
</head>

<body>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Image</th>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>Columt 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr id="row">
            <td>Image goes here</td>
            <td>Text 1</td>
            <td>Text 2</td>
            <td>Text 3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>


</html>
```

I don't know what differs on your side.
Try this piece of code if you want, and if it works compare it with your code.

Comment: Hey Fraximus, It is a sample code, I have modified it here to make it more readable, else the code is working fine.

Comment: I added a piece of code similar to your code, and tried it on my side. It's working. I can't pinpoint where the problem in your code is.
Is there a difference between my code and yours?

Comment: Hey Fraximus, You are appending the table row on the same page, But I am using shadow box to generate a pop up and then from that pop up I am sending this row on the parent page.

Comment: Then I'll look a bit more into shadowbox now and will update you when I find something.